# Animation with orientation change of Android device

Tags: java, beginner, android

I've started my first "job" like 2 weeks ago, and to be honest I've received a quite hard task to do, since I'm beginner with Android, and quite fresh at programming. The thing I needed was to find the way to rotate the buttons while changing orientation of the phone, after some research I've found a solution on the web, and after adapting it for my purposes the functionality worked.

What I'm asking you for is to guide me on how I could refactor the code.  My boss mentioned that in the `OrientationListener` class onOrientationChanged method repeats it's implementation with the same kind of objects and that the code is doubled.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ZoomListener, View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 512;

private Animation toLandAnim, toPortAnim, toRevPortAnim, toRevLandAnim;
private OrientationListener orientationListener;

private ImageButton zoomIn;
private ImageButton zoomOut;
private ImageButton cameraSwitch;

private TextView mCameraStatusTv;
private CameraView cameraPreview;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mCameraStatusTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.camera_status);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    zoomIn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnZoomIn);
    zoomIn.setOnClickListener(this);

    zoomOut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnZoomOut);
    zoomOut.setOnClickListener(this);

    cameraSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCameraSwitch);
    cameraSwitch.setOnClickListener(this);

    toLandAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate90degrees);
    toPortAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_anticlockwise);
    toRevPortAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate180degrees);
    toRevLandAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate270deegres);

    orientationListener = new OrientationListener(this);

    cameraPreview = (CameraView) findViewById(R.id.custom_preview);
    cameraPreview.setTestResultListener(this);


}

   @Override protected void onStart() {
    orientationListener.enable();
    super.onStart();
}
}


  public class OrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {
    final int ROTATION_O = 1;
    final int ROTATION_90   = 2;
    final int ROTATION_180  = 3;
    final int ROTATION_270  = 4;

    private int rotation = 0;
    public OrientationListener(Context context) { super(context); }


    @Override public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        if( (orientation < 35 || orientation > 325) && rotation!= ROTATION_O){ // request portrait mode
            rotation = ROTATION_O;

            zoomIn.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
            zoomOut.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
            cameraSwitch.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
        }
        else if( orientation > 145 && orientation < 215 && rotation!=ROTATION_180){ // request reverse portrait mode
            rotation = ROTATION_180;

            zoomIn.startAnimation(toRevPortAnim);
            zoomOut.startAnimation(toRevPortAnim);
            cameraSwitch.startAnimation(toRevPortAnim);


        }
        else if(orientation > 235 && orientation < 305 && rotation!=ROTATION_270){ // request reverse landscape mode
            rotation = ROTATION_270;

            zoomIn.startAnimation(toRevLandAnim);
            zoomOut.startAnimation(toRevLandAnim);
            cameraSwitch.startAnimation(toRevLandAnim);


        }
        else if(orientation > 55 && orientation < 125 && rotation!=ROTATION_90){ // request landscape mode
            rotation = ROTATION_90;

            zoomIn.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
            zoomOut.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
            cameraSwitch.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I'd recommend:

Create a ZoomInZoomOut method which contains the zoomin/zoomout code and then call it whenever you need it. For example:

```
public void ZoomInOut(Animation toPortAnim){
    zoomIn.startAnimation(toRevPortAnim);
    zoomOut.startAnimation(toRevPortAnim);
    cameraSwitch.startAnimation(toRevPortAnim);
    return;
}

if( (orientation < 35 || orientation > 325) && rotation!= ROTATION_O){ // request portrait mode
    rotation = ROTATION_O;
    ZoomInOut(toPortAnim);
}
//etc
```

This allows you to make changes later on which will affect all four if statements, which I'm sure that is what your boss meant by it being redundant.